# Using URL parameter in welcome message

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, url

Can I use the URL parameter, for example: `{{store direct_url="contact"}}`, in the welcome message input in `configuration > design` in some way?

I know HTML can be used there, so why not the URL parameter?

I am talking about this input field in the backend, at 'Welcome Text':
[image]

Comment: can You explain in more detail with example

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala added a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not possible, because this value is not passed through the cms processor.
Magento just load it from the config: `/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Header.php`

```
$this->_data['welcome'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/welcome');
```

---

But, you can do it by your own. The Welcome message is set in: `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/header.phtml`

in Line :39

```
<p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome') ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?></p>
```

You can pass it through the processor like this:

```
<p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo echo Mage::helper('cms')->getPageTemplateProcessor()->filter($this->getChildHtml('welcome')); ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?></p>
```

This is just a proof of concept. It would be better if you create your own block with your own function like `getParsedWelcomeMessage()` or something like this and call this function in your template.